# Distinguishing Tamil speakers from Sinhalese speakers in Sri Lanka

Tags: languages, sri-lanka

When in Sri Lanka I would like to use a few words of either Tamil or Sinhalese with the locals. How can I tell which language I should try? Are there cultural appearances that I can go from? Of I get it wrong would anyone be offended?

If so I could be better off sticking with English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not an easy task if you are planning to know the difference by looks, they both have the same skin color (some say Sinhalese have lighter skin color, but this is not true).

The easiest method to know which language to use is geographical distribution. Most Sinhalese live in south, west and most of the middle parts of Sri Lanka; while Tamil live in narrow strips in the northern and eastern part of Sri Lanka.

Other fact, Sinhalese are 75% of the population in Sri Lanka (15 millions), while Tamil are only 25% (5 millions).

Here is a map showing the geographical distribution of Tamil and Sinhalese:

[image: Sinhala vs tamil]

Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Distribution_of_Languages_and_Religious_groups_of_Sri_Lanka_1981.jpg)

Another good method to distinguish between the two language is the language itself, Sinhala is of an Indo-Aryan origins, it sounds like Hindi, while Tamil is a Dravidian language which makes it sound like Malayalam or Kannada languages or any other southern Indian language. If you are familiar with any of these languages or at least know how they sound, you will easily know the difference as they are totally different in everything especially pronunciations.

If you are not sure, just use English. If the person does not understand English, use Sinhala as it is widely understood even among the Tamil.

Comment: I'm not sure if "Sinhala sounds like Hindi" is correct. Although, it's Indo aryan. Lot's of vocabulary is also from Tamil. I know well how Hindi sounds like as I work with them everyday. I watched some sinhalese videos, it "sounded" to me more like Tamil/Malayalam than Hindi. But of course, I couldn't find any word that I already know may be  it was too fast for me. (Telugu is Dravidian but lots of everyday words are Sanskrit loan words). Just a hunch. Probably a bit subjective.

Comment: I was looking at that map and wondering, hello! where do all the whatever-speaking atheists live?

Answer (score 17):

Since the author of the accepted answer does not seem to be from Sri Lanka (no offense, sir), I'd like to add a Sri Lankan answer to this.

Most of the Sri Lankans (Sinhala or Tamil speaking) can speak English to some degree. If you are in Colombo or Kandy, there is a very good chance that the person you are speaking can understand English. English is a requirement to hire for sales department in most of the super markets and other shops so go ahead and speak English. Just try to maintain a slow and clear accent.

There are 3 major ethnic groups here - Sinhalese, Tamils and Muslims. Muslims usually speak both languages. Overall, Tamil and Muslim people can speak Sinhala just like other Sinhala people do. Both Tamil and Sinhala languages, however, are difficult to understand and how you pronounce the word will also make a difference.

MeNoTalk's answer is just perfect and just refer the map. However, even in the areas that the map says Tamil speaking people are a lot, you will find people who speak Sinhala fluently.

> When in Sri Lanka I would like to use a few words of either Tamil or
>   Sinhalese with the locals.

That is great. Speak with anyone in their own language and don't be surprised if they do their best to help you or make friends with you. Everyone here is very friendly.

> Are there cultural appearances that I can go from?
>   Yes. Tamil people, in most cases in the morning, go to their religious places. They have some dot in the forehead and Tamil women usually have white color decorations in their head (and relatively darker skin color compared to the rest).

One easy way would be to look at the sign boards of shops. If that's a Tamil only board, or have the Tamil version first, that's a sign and Tamils are there or many of them speak Tamil. But that's not the case every time. I'm a Sinhalese and I go to Tamil shops and their religious places (known as "Kovil"). They do the same.

> I get it wrong would anyone be offended?

Not at all. Just use your hand gestures and make them feel that you really need to speak their language. Don't forget to smile. I have seen many tourists speak a little louder which is not really necessary. 
If a girl has a Muslim scarf (I don't know the actual name), and is with her mother of father, speak with their parents and not their daughter - that's kinda offensive to approach such girl but overall, you'll be welcomed everywhere.

Comment: this gives the best answer. no doubts about it.

Comment: Hey Ayesh, the other answer tells that Sinhala sounds like Hindi since it's Indo Aryan. But I watched some Sinhala videos today, and sound wise it sounded more like Tamil than Hindi(I know that Sinhalese is Indo Aryan but still vocabulary wise?). Can you confirm? I hear Hindi and Tamil daily basis here in India.

Comment: Being a Sinhalese native speaker and some ability to speak Tamil, they are definitely more alike than Hindi. There are many words that are 100% same ("Amma" for mother for example) or are very close ("Nagar" and "Puram" in Tamil, "Nagaraya" and "Pura" in Sinhalese. All those words mean city) in pronunciation.

Roots of Sinhalese is Aryan languages, but Sri Lanka had more releationships with India for the past 2500 years, which makes the more Tamil-like Sinhalese today.

Answer (score 5):

I spent 16days in Sri Lanka and I am from South India. I speak Tamil pretty well, but it didn't help me much except at Jaffna and Nuwara Eliya. English is widely understood by people in hospitality segment. Sometimes at the interior parts, communication was a big issue. Learning a few words -salutation, apology ,appreciation -will make a big difference. Sri Lanka is a very tourist friendly place, so you wouldn't struggle much with language.

Comment: A very relevant answer. +1